How to generate a roofline analysis by Nsight?
When I was trying to analyze the performance of a kernel, I used ncu command to generate a report. However, it didn't display the roofline analysis under the section "GPU Speed of Light Troughput". It gave me a piece of information that

The ratio of peak float (fp32) to double (fp64) performance on this device is 64:1. The kernel achieved 0% of this device's fp32 peak performance and 0% of its fp64 peak performance.

However, the kernel actually did many flops. I don't know what happened and how to fix it.
My ncu version is:
NVIDIA (R) Nsight Compute Command Line Profiler
Copyright (c) 2018-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Version 2023.3.0.0 (build 33266684) (public-release)

My command line is
ncu -f --launch-count 50 --set full --export profile_rep ./my_program

I tried to find the answer through Internet but I didn't find the solution. Their ncu all seems work well. I even download others open source codes and test their kernels. The roofline analysis is still missing while others can generate that. I would be very grateful if you can help me find my mistakes when using ncu or solve this problem.

I have the same problem on my machine (with a Nvidia 1660S GPU) on all kernel so far. Other profiling informations are reported very well (AFAIR things like SASS instructions, memory stalls, branch divergence, memory bandwidth, kernel timings, occupancy, etc.). My Nsight version is either 2024.3.0 or 2024.1.1.

You are aware that in the GUI you need to click the arrow/triangle element to the left of "GPU Speed Of Light Throughput" to expand the details for the section including the roofline plot?

Thank you, I find that after clicking the triangle element to the left of "GPU Speed Of Light Throughput", there is a box for me to select on the right hand side. Click it and choose "All". Then, the roofline appears.

Interesting, for me the triangle is enough. Feel free to answer yourself with some screenshots for reference.
